# What is the viewValue in the following AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I like to use the `ui.bootstrap.datepicker` directive with a specific format returned to ng-model. This has already been answered in this thread ([DatePicker Have the Model come back as a specific format.](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/960)). However, I don't understand what `return +viewValue;` does in the given solution. Can someone please tell me what this line of code mean? Thanks.
[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XiPs5uhDSG5SlHMZdkTI?p=preview)

```
app.directive('myformat', function() {
  return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
        return +viewValue; //????????? what is this doing?
            });
        }
    }
});
```